# Dot Net Framework 3.5 installation Error

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework, maya

I am trying to install Dot Net Framework 3.5 in Windows 8, i had also tried the solutions given on the web using the command(offline) as well as online downloading and installing it but can't install it My OS is Windows 8(64-bit) and i want to install  Maya 3D Animation Software on my machine and still getting the same Error which shows that, this application needs .net framework 3.5...... Please help me to solve this big problem..

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a feature?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AthomSfere Yes, i have tried these methods but can't install

Comment: What error do you get when trying to install 3.5? Your question needs a lot of work, fill in some steps, errors, what you have tried in depth. This is a Q&A site, not a help forum so going back and forth for nuggets of information is not productive.

Comment: 1) Initially i had uninstalled the updates from the Control panel --> Program and features --> view Installed updates                                         2) After that i clicked on the Turn windows feature on or off in the same program and feature option                                                                       3)Then checked the check box in front of the .net framework 3.5 and after that tried to install the files from net finally the downloading never ends.

Comment: have you tried the DISM command?